# how to register User Information in to database using execute method

Tags: java, struts

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>

    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="registerform" type="com.register.actions.DynaActionForm">

            <form-property name="emailid" type=""></form-property>
            <form-property name="password" type=""></form-property>
            <form-property name="cpassword" type=""></form-property>
            <form-property name="firstname" type=""></form-property>
            <form-property name="lastname" type=""></form-property>
            <form-property name="gender" type=""></form-property>
            <form-property name="submitError" type=""></form-property>


        </form-bean>
    </form-beans>

    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/doRegister" type="com.register.actions.UserRegistrationAction"
            name="registerform" scope="request" validate="true" input="input">
            <forward name="input" path="/index.jsp" />
            <forward name="success" path="/welcome.jsp" />
            <forward name="failure" path="/index.jsp" />
        </action>

    </action-mappings>

    <controller inputForward="true" />
    <message-resources parameter="com.register.util.ApplicationResources" />
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property property="pathnames"
            value="/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml,
                             /WEB-INF/validation.xml" />
        <set-property property="stopOnFirstError" value="true" />
    </plug-in>
</struts-config>
```

This is My DynaAction form

```
    package com.register.model;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

    import com.register.util.ConnectionUtils;
    import com.register.util.DbUtils;

    public class UserRegistration extends User{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public boolean newuserregistration() throws Exception
        {
            PreparedStatement psUserRegistration = null;
            String sqlUserRegistration = null;

            boolean isRegistered = false;

            Connection conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();

            sqlUserRegistration = "insert into user_master(sEmail, sPassword, sFirstName," +
                                  " sLastName, cGender, iUserType, sCreatedDate, cStatus)" +
                                  " values(?,md5(?),?,?,?,1,sysdate(),'A')";

            try{
                psUserRegistration = conn.prepareStatement(sqlUserRegistration);
                psUserRegistration.setString(1, this.getEmail());
                psUserRegistration.setString(2, this.getPassword());
                psUserRegistration.setString(3, this.getFirstName());
                psUserRegistration.setString(4, this.getLastName());
                psUserRegistration.setString(5, this.getGender());
                psUserRegistration.executeUpdate();

                isRegistered=true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                String errorMessage=e.getMessage(); 
                e.printStackTrace();
                if(errorMessage.indexOf("Duplicate entry")>=0)
                {
                    this.setDbError("error");
                }
                isRegistered=false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DbUtils.close(psUserRegistration, conn);

            return isRegistered;
        }
    }

This is database connection class for all .





package com.register.actions;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages;
import org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm;

import com.register.model.UserRegistration;

public class UserRegistrationAction  extends Action{
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        boolean action_perform = false;
        String action_target;

        UserRegistration u = new UserRegistration();

        ActionMessages errors_mesg = new ActionMessages();

        //UserRegisterForm uf = (UserRegisterForm) form;


        DynaActionForm uf=(DynaActionForm) form;
        return null;

    }
}
```

This is Action class : i want to register User detail to database please tell me how i will write code for registration user detail to database . registration working finewith ActionForm but i have to create Using DynaActionForm please help me i am new and try to learn struts framework

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.register.actions;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages;
import org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm;

import com.register.model.UserRegistration;

public class UserRegistrationAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        boolean action_perform = false;
        String action_target;

        UserRegistration u = new UserRegistration();

        ActionMessages errors_mesg = new ActionMessages();

        // UserRegisterForm uf = (UserRegisterForm) form;

        DynaActionForm uf = (DynaActionForm) form;

        String emailid = uf.getString("emailid");
        String password = uf.getString("password");
        String cpassword = uf.getString("cpassword");
        String firstname = uf.getString("firstname");
        String lastname = uf.getString("lastname");
        String gender = uf.getString("gender");
        String submitError = uf.getString("submitError");

        // System.out.println(emailid);
        if (form != null)

        {

            u.setEmail(emailid);

            u.setPassword(cpassword);
            // u.setEmail(emailid);
            u.setFirstName(firstname);
            u.setLastName(lastname);
            u.setGender(gender);
            // u.setEmail(cpassword);
            action_perform = u.newuserregistration();
            String sError = u.getDbError();
            if (sError.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
                errors_mesg.add("submitError", new ActionMessage(
                        "errors.user.registration.email.duplicate"));
                saveErrors(request, errors_mesg);
            }

        }

        if (action_perform == false) {
            errors_mesg.add("submitError", new ActionMessage(
                    "errors.user.registration.fail"));
            saveErrors(request, errors_mesg);
            action_target = "failure";
        } else {
            errors_mesg.add("submitError", new ActionMessage(
                    "errors.user.registration.success"));
            saveErrors(request, errors_mesg);
            action_target = "success";
        }

        return mapping.findForward(action_target);

    }
}
```

I have Tried this code and working Fine now so now i understand basic differnce Between Action Form and DynaAction form .